# How to allocate memory to a 2D array of objects in c++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Three classes Zoo, ZooObject and Animal are present.Is it valid to declare a 2D array of ZooObjects like mentioned below? If so, how do i initialise it? I am familiar with dynamically allocating a 2D array, but can't figure out this one.

```
class ZooObject;

class Zoo {
 public:
  int rows, cols;
  ZooObject ***zooArray;

  Zoo(int rows, int cols) {
    this->rows = rows;
    this->cols = cols;
    // dynamically initialize ***zooArray as a 2D array with each 
    //element of type Animal
    // initially initialized to NULL.


 // initialize each row first.
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      zooArray[i] = new ZooObject *[cols];
    }

    // initialize each column.
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        Animal animal;
        zooArray[i][j] = &animal;
      }
    }
  }
};

class ZooObject {
 public:
  bool isAlive;
};

class Animal : public ZooObject {
 public:
  bool isHerbivore;
};

int main() { Zoo *zoo = new Zoo(3, 3); }
```

Comment: @francesco i'm familiar with this construct. But can't figure out for this specific case.

Comment: But what of the possibilities in the answers to the question I linked you would like to implement? A 1D array? An array of pointers?

Comment: @francesco i've updated my code. Can you check is this the correct way?

Comment: When you say you want a 2D array, I think there should be just one allocation, no arrays of pointers.

Comment: You are better off using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already was mentioned, here is nice post where the general answer to the question was detailing explained.
[How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

In your case, if you want to store this as 2D array. You should allocate first all rows, where each row is a `ZooObject**`, which is `ZooObject` `s pointers array.
And after, for each of the row, you should allocate the array (columns) of `ZooObject*`. You will have something like this:

```cpp
    Zoo(int rows, int cols) {
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;

        zooArray = new ZooObject**[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            zooArray[i] = new ZooObject*[cols];
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                zooArray[i][j] = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, consider using 1D arrays, you still can access it via 2 dimensions, via corresponding method, which converting `rowId, colId` pair to 1D dimension.

Also, don't forget to `delete` which you `new`!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can even have further classes inheriting from the base class Animal like Carnivorous, Herbivorous etc. Hence, Animal will be an abstract class. I believe this initialisation `zooArray[i][j] = new Animal;` will throw error.

Comment: @taurus05, you are right. We can store any of the derived classes object in the cell, as the cell has the type `ZooObject*`.
`new Animal` is an example. It's better to assign `nullptr` there, and later assign the correct object that we want.

Comment: @BonnyCash Thank you!

Comment: When you say you want a 2D array, I think there should be just one allocation, no arrays of pointers.

Comment: I want a 2D array of pointers.

Comment: @taurus05 you need a virtual desctructor in your base class (it is *unusable* without a virtual destructor)  and then you need more virtual functions (it is *not very useful* without  them). "I believe this initialisation zooArray[i][j] = new Animal; will throw error". Why do you think so? It is certainly infinitely better than `Animal animal; zooArray[i][j] = &animal;`.